# Get attribute value from XML with TestComplete Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, testcomplete

I need to get value of **enabled attribute** from element *<testItem name="Phase0" ...>*

Could someone tell me how to do it? I don't know how to do it..

I tried something to help xpath but no result.

The document is loaded but I don't know how to get the attribute value

```
function getAttrValue()
{
  var fileName = "C:\\test.xml";
  var doc = Sys.OleObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");

  doc.load(fileName);

  var value = doc.selectSingleNode("/Root/testItems/children/testItem(1)/children/testItem(0)").enabled;
  Log.Message(value);
}
```

the xml code is not complete... it's too long

Thank you

```
<Root signature="{362A8EE5-675E-43A9-869D-06ECE80B0CB4}" version="14.0">
    
    <testItems key="{18FBEBF5-E1A7-4B44-A78F-4BDB66ECB279}" version="14">
        <children>
            <testItem name="SETENVIRONMENT" key="{69AEF7E8-30A3-4AA3-B44A-F6F5A0812578}" group="True" parallel="False" enabled="True" testMoniker="" count="1" timeout="0" stopOnError="3" stopOnException="2" description="" tmsData="" testCase="True">
                <testParameters />
                <children>
                    <testItem name="Automate" key="{A9BBB245-02DE-4F1D-BEE8-9B3A576E0F04}" group="False" parallel="False" enabled="True" testMoniker="{088295FE-07C1-4A44-83FE-27198978BB3A}AutomateProcessRun" count="1" timeout="0" stopOnError="1" stopOnException="2" description="" tmsData="" testCase="True">
                        <testParameters />
                        <environments activeCloud="CBT" />
                        <children />
                    </testItem>
                </children>
            </testItem>   
            <testItem name="TESTCASES" key="{F27CAF00-67B1-44D6-9D6B-B8A1498AB787}" group="True" parallel="False" enabled="True" testMoniker="" count="1" timeout="0" stopOnError="3" stopOnException="2" description="" tmsData="" testCase="True">
                <testParameters />
                <children>
                    <testItem name="Phase0" key="{6D5E60D6-FC79-4ABE-9E4E-95625C081D45}" group="False" parallel="False" enabled="True" testMoniker="KDT\{B024E0F5-9C6E-43B4-BA21-D79A54AF1B61}" count="1" timeout="0" stopOnError="1" stopOnException="2" description="" tmsData="" testCase="True">
                        <testParameters />
                        <environments activeCloud="CBT" />
                        <children />
                    </testItem>
                    <testItem name="Phase1" key="{2D49F60C-20B6-4D73-8FC5-FA57B1AA6677}" group="False" parallel="False" enabled="True" testMoniker="KDT\{28D6EBB9-B449-407B-942B-E43C7A6E5E7B}" count="1" timeout="0" stopOnError="1" stopOnException="2" description="" tmsData="" testCase="True">
                        <testParameters />
                        <environments activeCloud="CBT" />
                        <children />
                    </testItem>
                    <testItem name="Phase2" key="{EB2033B4-6AB6-409C-8674-90B1CB4C2288}" group="False" parallel="False" enabled="True" testMoniker="KDT\{AB04AC00-EC2F-4CDE-AB21-95327EDC97AE}" count="1" timeout="0" stopOnError="1" stopOnException="2" description="" tmsData="" testCase="True">
                        <testParameters />
                        <environments activeCloud="CBT" />
                        <children />
                    </testItem>
                    <testItem name="Phase3" key="{8C5DC219-A594-4790-AF51-CA3FAD21F722}" group="False" parallel="False" enabled="True" testMoniker="KDT\{12B9102E-1E90-4D4F-8B1D-A1AD951BDC85}" count="1" timeout="0" stopOnError="1" stopOnException="2" description="" tmsData="" testCase="True">
                        <testParameters />
                        <environments activeCloud="CBT" />
                        <children />
                    </testItem>
                    <testItem name="Phase4" key="{8785B649-B1B5-4A7A-8543-21AD95718EC6}" group="False" parallel="False" enabled="True" testMoniker="KDT\{890BAA92-FF2C-468B-AF0C-80E397C63EE4}" count="1" timeout="0" stopOnError="1" stopOnException="2" description="" tmsData="" testCase="True">
                        <testParameters />
                        <environments activeCloud="CBT" />
                        <children />
                    </testItem>
                </children>
            </testItem>
        </children>
    </testItems>
</Root>
```

Comment: *I tried something* ... doesn't look like it ...

Comment: "the xml code is not complete... it's too long" - while that may be true, your question needs to contain a short, representative and **well formed** sample of the xml.

Comment: @JackFleeting I think the embedded xml is fine now. I had to edit

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not well formed. Try running it through [an xml validator](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html).

Comment: @JackFleeting yes sorry...  thank you for the warning ... corrected and valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the caveat that I wasn't able to try it myself, it seems your problem has to do with handling namespaces. One simple way (doesn't always work) is to sidestep them altogether. See what happens if you replace

```
doc.selectSingleNode("/Root/testItems/children/testItem(1)/children/testItem(0)")
```

with

```
doc.selectSingleNode("//*[local-name()="testItem"][@name="Phase0"]/@enabled")
```